# How to request data from remote graphql to be used as global values through the app?

Tags: next.js, graphql

I am struggling to find a solution to this...

I would like to fetch some data from the remote CMS, via graphql, which I can access on any page through the app, without having to define/fetch it all on a per page basis. I should not have any code on the pages to fetch this data.

I discovered "global" in which I can assign any value to, for example, in _app.js I can set:

```
global.my_data = "test"
```

Then on any page this will show the value "test"

```
{my_data}
```

So I proceed to fetch the data I want from the remote CMS using GraphQL.

Now, if I dont use async/await, then global.my_data = response, never gets initiated, it's like the query blocks it. If I use async/await then my pages all get rendered before the query, so my_data does not exist on the page.

Here are some examples, this is in _app.js:

The following with async/await does not create the global.my_data before pages are built, so my_data does not exist in the pages:

```
export const globalData = async() => {

    const mydata = await request(
        `https://example.com/graphql`,
        gql`
        query Data
        {
            mydata
        }       
        `
    ).then((response) => {
        global.my_data = mydata;
    })
}
```

The following without await/async returns a Promise:

```
    export const globalData = () => {
    
        const mydata = request(
            `https://example.com/graphql`,
            gql`
            query Data
            {
                mydata
            }       
            `
        )
        global.my_data = mydata
    }
```

How can I fetch data from my remote CMS that can be assigned a global variable accessed on all pages?

I guess I need to know how to fetch the data at build time? Or fetch the data before processing all the other pages.

I could put it in next.config.js and assign it to env, and access it with process.env.my_data but I am not sure next.config.js is the best place to fetch and store CMS data is it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close. The pattern I tend to use is an object that you `init` or `load` followed by a getter. The key is to keep the value in the object's state by declaring it outside the function body.

Example:

```
let myGlobalState;
const url = 'https://example.com/graphql';
const query = gql`
  query Data
    {
      mydata
    }       
`;

export const myGlobals = {
  async load() {
    myGlobalState = await request(url,query);
  },
  get() { return myGlobalState }
}
```

When your program first runs you can invoke `await myGlobals.load()` and know that your state has been loaded. Later you can invoke `myGlobals.get()` to access it. With this pattern the loading is async but the getting is synchronous.